# Node https.Agent in browser

Tags: node.js, typescript, npm

Part of my npm module (typescript) is using axios to make web requests. One of the possible endpoints is using certificates for authentication. For this scenario I'm passing `new https.Agent` to axios to send the certificates info. All is working fine if the module is used from within Node app.

The problem is if I try and use my module in browser environment. When in browser `https` module do not exists and I'm unable to use my module.

- Is there any way to use `https` module in the browser?
- If not - can `https` be bundled within my module somehow? Do I have to use some bundler in this case (like Rollup) to build the typescript module?

Comment: You can't easily move code from one host environment to another without polyfills, and even then, you have to stay up to date with the polyfills as browsers change. I suggest a third bullet: How do I rewrite my code using browser native code?

Comment: completely agree with you. Unfortunately I couldn't find a way to send requests with certificates from the browser without https agent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do it. Most browsers support TLS Client Certificate authentication, but it works differently: the user is presented with a window and asked to select a certificate to authenticate with. It's a similar story to how cookies work - you can't easily manipulate HttpOnly cookies from JS on the client side.

If you want TLS client auth in the browser, you are at the browser vendor's mercy.